# Execute Shell commands in Python code

Tags: c++, c++20

I wrote a little C++ program that lets me transpile a syntax that allows running Shell in Python to legal Python and then execute it. Here is an example input:

> ```py
> filename = f'./data/lines.txt'
> n_lines = int(`wc -l {filename}`.split()[0])
> print(n_lines, 'lines in file')
> ```

This is transpiled to:

> ```py
> import subprocess
>
> filename = f'./data/lines.txt'
> _ = subprocess.run(f'wc -l {filename}'.split(), capture_output=True).stdout.decode('utf-8').strip()
> n_lines = int(_.split()[0])
> print(n_lines, 'lines in file')
> ```

and then executed. My main code is:

main.py

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <memory>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include "formatter.h"

/** Process a single line.
 *
 * @param line - The line to process
 * @return The processed Python code
 */
std::string process_line(std::string& line)
{
    std::ostringstream generated;

    // Parse template args in the string.
    if (line.find("`") != std::string::npos) {
        // Find all indices.
        std::vector<size_t> cmd_idx;
        size_t cur_tick_idx = 0;
        size_t next_tick_idx;

        // Find all backticks
        while ((next_tick_idx = line.find("`", cur_tick_idx)) != std::string::npos) {
            // First, check that it is not escaped.
            if (next_tick_idx <= 0 || line[next_tick_idx - 1] != '\\')
                cmd_idx.push_back(next_tick_idx);

            cur_tick_idx = next_tick_idx + 1;
        }

        // Ensure we have an even number of indices
        if (cmd_idx.size() % 2 == 1)
            throw "Invalid number of template quotes";

        // Begin substitution using formatters.
        for (size_t i{}, j{1}; i < cmd_idx.size(); i += 2, j += 2) {
            std::string substr = line.substr(cmd_idx[i] + 1, cmd_idx[j] - cmd_idx[i] - 1);

            generated << "_ = subprocess.run(f'" << substr << "'.split(), capture_output=True).stdout.decode('utf-8').strip()\n";

            // Check for formatters
            if (cmd_idx[i] > 0 && (std::isalnum(line[cmd_idx[i] - 1]) || line[cmd_idx[i] - 1] == '_')) {
                size_t k;
                for (k = cmd_idx[i] - 2; k >= 0; --k) {
                    if (!std::isalnum(line[k]) && line[k] != '_')
                        break;
                }

                std::string format = line.substr(k + 1, cmd_idx[i] - k - 1);

                // Apply formatter
                // If "str", do nothing.
                if (format != "str") {
                    std::unique_ptr<type_formatter> formatter = std::make_unique<type_formatter>(format);
                    generated << formatter->format();
                }
            }

            // Now, replace the part in quotes with our variable
            generated << line.replace(cmd_idx[i], cmd_idx[j] - cmd_idx[i] + 1, "_");
        }
    } else {
        generated << line;
    }

    return generated.str();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // TODO: Change this to a filename input
    std::ifstream fin(argv[1]);
    std::ofstream fout("out.py");

    fout << "import subprocess\n\n";

    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(fin, line)) {
        fout << process_line(line) << std::endl;
    }

    fout.close();

    // Run the code
    const char* path = std::getenv("PATH");
    std::filesystem::path cur_path = std::filesystem::current_path();
    std::string new_path = std::string(path) + ":" + cur_path.string();

    if (setenv("PATH", new_path.c_str(), 1) != 0)
        throw "Failed to set PATH";

    std::system("python out.py");

    return 0;
}
```

and my formatter code is pretty simple:

formatter.cpp

```
#include "formatter.h"

type_formatter::type_formatter(const std::string& fmt) {
    this->fmt = fmt;
}

/**
 * Returns Python code that checks whether the string
 * can be safely casted to the desired type.
 * 
 * TODO: Check indent level
 */
std::string type_formatter::get_safe_formatter() {
    std::string check_cast_code = "try:\n\t"
        "_ = " + fmt + "(_)\nexcept ValueError:\n\t"
        "raise";

    return check_cast_code;
}

std::string type_formatter::format()
{
    if (fmt == "int" ||
        fmt == "float")
        return get_safe_formatter();

    if (fmt == "list")
        return "_ = _.split('\\n')\n";

    if (fmt.starts_with("list.")) {
        std::string list_type = fmt.substr(5);
        return "_ = [" + list_type + "(x) for x in _.split('\\n')]\n";
    }

    throw "Formatter for type does not exist.";
};
```

formatter.h

```
#ifndef FORMATTER_H
#define FORMATTER_H

#include <string>

/**
 * The base class for formatters. This is an abstract class
 * and should be extended to implement specific formatters.
 * Formatters must implement the `format()` function, which
 * should return a std::string containing Python code to process
 * a variable called _, which will contain the output from shell
 * code in the transpiled program. As a template, the code should
 * end up assigning _ to the correct type. The Python code should
 * end in a newline.
 */
class basic_formatter
{
public:
    basic_formatter() = default;
    virtual std::string format() = 0; 
};

class type_formatter : public basic_formatter
{
    std::string fmt;
    std::string get_safe_formatter();

public:
    type_formatter(const std::string&);
    type_formatter() = delete;
    virtual std::string format();
};

#endif
```

I primarily work with JS and Python, so I'm trying to understand how I can write better C++ code, what norms I've broken, what I could do better, etc. I'm using C++20.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code that's ready for review shouldn't have any outstanding `TODO` comments.  You should resolve those.

Instead of including both `<cstdlib>` and `<stdlib.h>`, use just the C++ header, and namespace-qualify `std::size_t` where it's used.

Class `basic_formatter` is intended for use as a base class.  You should provide a *virtual* destructor so that subclasses are correctly destroyed when deleted via a base-class pointer:

```
basic_formatter() = default;
virtual ~basic_formatter() = default;
```

In `type_formatter`, I don't think we want implicit conversion from strings, so mark that constructor with `explicit`.  Use the constructor's initializer-list to populate `fmt`, rather than letting it default-construct and then overwriting in the body.  And if we pass by value, we can avoid an extra copy in many cases.

```
explicit type_formatter(const std::string fmt)
    : fmt{std::move(fmt)}
{}
```

It's not necessary to declare a deleted no-args constructor - just omit this, as the above constructor inhibits generation of a default constructor.

The `format()` method should be declared `override` instead of `virtual`{

```
std::string format() override;
```

Consider whether you really want to allow `format()` to modify the formatter - perhaps it should be `const`?

When we construct a formatter, we make a smart pointer.  But we don't need to do that, as we can construct and use it directly:

```
            if (format != "str") {
                type_formatter formatter{format};
                generated << formatter.format();
            }
```

We have a logic error here:

```
            std::size_t k;
            for (k = cmd_idx[i] - 2; k >= 0; --k) {
```

That's an infinite loop, because `k >= 0` can never be false.  That's a sign of not enabling sufficient compiler warnings, and perhaps also of insufficient unit-testing.

When throwing, we should use appropriate subclasses of `std::exception`.  C++ allows us to throw a string literal, but that is generally considered a poor practice.  And we never catch anything we throw - that needs to be fixed.

`process_line()` shouldn't need to write to a string-stream and stringify the result, given that when we call it, we immediately write its result to another stream.  Just pass the output stream into the function (as a reference) and write to it directly.

The search for matching backquote characters is flawed.  A preceding backslash doesn't escape a backquote if the backslash itself is quoted - we'll need a smarter parser to give us real robustness here.

Lots of ways in which `main()` can misbehave, none of which give any diagnostic or exit status:

- input filename isn't readable
- unable to create or overwrite `out.py` in current directory (consider using `mktemp()` or similar to get somewhere safe to write)
- writing fails later (e.g. disk full)
- `python` is not on the path (likely in systems where the interpreters are called `python2` and/or `python3`).

We lose the exit status of the invoked Python program.  It's probably better to `exec()` rather than `std::system()` on POSIX systems, so that the caller gets the full exit status (including signal and core-dump information if appropriate).  Where only standard-library functions are available, consider using the return value from `std::system()` to determine what to return from `main()`.

Comment: This is fantastic and so helpful! Thank you so much! Are these things I can learn from a book (say Stroustrup's book), or is it mainly from practice?

Comment: I've been writing C++ for a long time, so the books I learnt from are completely outdated now (thought there's a lot that's still relevant, particularly Scott Myers's _Effective Modern C++_).  Practice is valuable, as is following and understanding reviews here and questions on [so].  Keep experimenting and bringing your code here for suggestions, and you'll gradually get better and better.  :)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Toby Speight mentioned:

## Expansion can happen in the wrong context

Consider the following Python input:

```
print("Never run `rm -rf .`")
```

Your transpiler will then run:

```
import subprocess

_ = subprocess.run(f'rm -rf .'.split(), capture_output=True).stdout.decode('utf-8').strip()
print("Never run _")
```

Deleting everything in the current directory, and printing a nonsensical message.

## Why not make a Python function?

Having to need a transpiler means adding dependencies to a project. It also introduces lots of problems, correctly parsing the input as mentioned above just being one of them. Consider that the original input might still work as a Python program, but will do something different if you forget to run it via the transpiler.

Why not just make a Python function that does the substitution for you, with a short name like `sh()`, so that you can write something like:

```
filename = f'./data/lines.txt'
n_lines = sh('wc -l < {filename}').as_int()
print(n_lines, 'lines in file')
```

This would keep everything in Python, so no need for external tools, and no surprises.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the edge case! I need to flesh out more scenarios to parse inputs better.

re why not Python: I just wanted to play around in C++ :) A Python solution would also help with things like Intellisense, something I would've had to build myself with my current solution--which would also be instructive, of course.